# If statement for number in a range

Tags: python, if-statement

I cannot tweak this for it to only respond to a value between 1 and 100. I know its somthing simple, but cannot find anything through searching that works.

```
while True:
    Mynumber = raw_input('Enter number of random points')
    if Mynumber == '0 < 100':
            print 'number choosen'
            Mynumber = int(Mynumber)
            break
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if 1 <= my_number <= 100:
```

Or, since you are grabbing from raw_input and have to convert to `int` from unknown string first:

```
try:
    my_number = int(raw_number)
except ValueError:
    print "%s not an integer value." % raw_number
else:
    if 1 <= raw_number <= 100:
```

Though on further analysis, it looks like you are trying to do:

```
base_prompt = 'Enter number of random points'
user_input = raw_input(base_prompt)
while True:
    try:
        input_number = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        user_input = raw_input('%s not an interger\n%s' % (user_input, base_prompt))
    else:
        if 1 <= input_number <= 100:
            break
        else:
            user_input = raw_input('%d out of range (1 to 100)\n%s' % (input_number, base_prompt))
```

Comment: Don't forget to make my_number an integer before doing this test :)

Comment: @mgilson Answered the question, then solved the unasked problems.  :)

Comment: To my defense, there isn't actually a question mark in that question ... :-p

Comment: I like the idea of it not accepting anything other than an integer but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Python 3.x, the following also works:

```
if int(my_number) in range(1, 101):
    # ...
```

The caveat is that the end point of a range is exclusive, so it probably reads less intuitively than chained operators.

Comment: It works in Python 2 too, it's just that `range()` produces a list in that case, and materializing that list and searching it costs more than using ethe python 3 `range()` type.

Comment: @sr2222: Martijn Pieters's comment explains _why_ it's inefficient in py2 (and why it isn't in py3).

Comment: @abarnert I think he edited it since I posted that to add more info.  You are correct in that hte current version makes my comment pretty redundant...

Comment: Or in python 2, use `if int(my_number) in xrange(1, 101):`

Comment: Right, to be more precise, it **works** in both Python 2 and 3, but is only a good idea in Python 3.

Comment: @Eric: It's too slow to be useful with `xrange()` as well as with `range()` in Python 2. Python 2's `xrange()` doesn't define `__contains__()`, so the `in` operator will just convert it to a list.